# Synonyms in Solr two-ways

Tags: solr, synonym

I want Solr 4 to return synonyms in two-ways for a given synonyms list.

**Indexed content**

```
Nice villa front of the sea
Looking for condo around 2 billions $
Superb house with 3 bedrooms
Flat for sale
```

**synonyms.txt**

```
#Equivalent synonyms may be separated with commas and give
#no explicit mapping.  In this case the mapping behavior will
#be taken from the expand parameter in the schema.  This allows
#the same synonym file to be used in different synonym handling strategies.

villa, house, home, condo, appartement, residence, flat
```

**schema.xml**

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="false"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>

<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Actually:

Search "villa" returns all results but if i search for any other word in Synonyms.txt I don't get anything else than the corresponding sentence.

ie flat returns:

```
Flat for sale
```

ie house returns:

```
Superb house with 3 bedrooms
```

I would like all synonyms (flat, house, condo, etc) return same as "villa" keyword.

Comment: The synonym filter should be after the tokenizer - try moving it and see if that helps (since you won't have a stream consisting of separate tokens before tokenization has happened).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your analyzer configuration.

- "The synonym filter should be *after* the tokenizer" as MatsLindh pointed out
- `LowerCaseFilter` should come before the `SynonymFilter`. Otherwise, in your example, Flat would be ignored since it's not all in lowercase.
- The `PhoneticFilter` should have `inject` set to `true`, as you're now only stemming the phonetic token instead of the original one.

Try with this config:

```xml
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"
          synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
  <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Comment: Actually SynonymFilter would probably still work with non-lowercase since you have ignoreCase="true", but still better to place it after the LowercaseFilter.

Comment: Ok and what I should put in my query analyzer ? Actually I have :           <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>

Comment: I would start by having the exact query config as the index time. You can make a case to remove SynonymFilter from query completely in case of multiword synonyms, but I would leave it the same for now.